# Facebook android misconfiguration

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using a new version of the Facebook SDK, in my android app, where the Util.java class is deprecated and hence I can't find the ENABLE_LOG variable at all (which all the current solutions online ask us to find and change). Instead I had to enable log in the facebook manifest using . And even then there was no log error. This error (misconfiguration) occurs even though I've used the keyhash generated by the .keystore file which I used to sign my app before release.

The issue got resolved only when I deleted the Facebook app from my phone, which is ridiculous. Does anyone know the actual solution to this problem?

Comment: Try the answer I posted here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13966906/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-not-returning-the-logcat-after-setti

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For now I've solved it by reverting to the older sdk and changing the value of the ENABLE_LOG variable. But I'll look into your answer sometime soon and let you know. :)